# Stretching of WPF StackPanel

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls, wpf-controls, stackpanel

I'm playing around with WPF and I'm trying to create an `ImageButton` control. I've created a `UserControl` as follows:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Class="WpfPractise.Controls.ImageButton"
         Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="ImageButtonControl">
<Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Source="{Binding Image, ElementName=ImageButtonControl}"
               Width="16" Height="16"
           Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=ImageButtonControl}"
           Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This is working fine except for the StackPanel doesn't stretch to fill the width or the height! I've tried a Grid in it's place but to no avail. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: The `StackPanel` doesn't stretch to fit the `Width` and `Height` of what?

Comment: Of the Button. It sits in the centre whereas I want the Image to be aligned to the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to align the `Button` content to the left then you have to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the button

```
   <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image, ElementName=ImageButtonControl}"
           Width="16" Height="16"
       Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=ImageButtonControl}"
       Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Comment: That would certainly make sense! Thank you.